# How to display only selected information in my collection_select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following code below:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :emp_role_id, "Employee Role" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :emp_role_id, EmpRole.all, :id, :emp_rolename %>
</div>
```

In my EmpRole, there are Owner, Manager, Shift Leader, and Sales Employee.  I'm creating a self sign up form, which allows the employees to sign themselves up to use the application.

Currently, anyone who signs up by using this method can be a owner and manager, however, I would like anyone who signs up only have the privilege of the Shift Leader and Sales Employee role.  Is there anyway I can filter out the other 2 options and only show "Sales Employee" and "Shift Leader" by using collection_select?

Comment: I think you can select roles you want by: `EmpRole.all.where.not(emp_rolename: ['Owner', 'Manager'])` instead of using `EmpRole.all` in your collection_select.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can try this

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :emp_role_id, "Employee Role" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :emp_role_id, EmpRole.where("emp_rolename IN (?)", ["Sales Employee", "Shift Leader"]), :id, :emp_rolename %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey  **Milind** , We can definitely use sql query in a view, and we also can use active record scope. So this is not a bad practice.

Comment: As I said, there is no good or bad good, its just a optimal code, so while testing the above piece of code, you also have to include a select query in the test file, which looks bad.Anyways its a developers call to take care of it, we can just guide him though.

Answer (score 1):

Two SOLUTIONs....

**SOLUTION FIRST**

```
##############in emp model..emp.rb####################


ADMIN_ROLES = %w[SUPERADMIN ADMIN BIGADMIN].freeze
SIMPLE_ROLES = %w[SHIFTLEADER SALESLEADER BLAH BLAH].freeze

scope :get_simple_roles_only, -> { where(:name => SIMPLE_ROLES) }


##############in the view file ###################
  <%= f.collection_select :emp_role_id, EmpRole.get_simple_roles_only.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]} || f.rolename) %>
```

**SOLUTION SECOND** > use [delete_if](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if)

```
 <%= f.collection_select :emp_role_id, EmpRole.all.delete_if {|a| a.emp_rolename  == ['ROLENAME1', 'ROLENAME1'].map{|s| [s.id, s.name]} %>
```

I would recommend first one, as its very dynamic and can be changed on demand.

Hope it helps